# Typing [status-*] in chat shows red moderator tag

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags, chat

In Chat, if you type `[status-*]` (where * is anything), a red moderator-tag is shown:

[How it works http://static.maximzaslavsky.com/images/other/How%20it%20works.PNG](http://static.maximzaslavsky.com/images/other/How%20it%20works.PNG)

Unfortunately, this can **create *havoc***:

[this won't end well http://static.maximzaslavsky.com/images/other/This%20wont%20end%20well.PNG](http://static.maximzaslavsky.com/images/other/This%20wont%20end%20well.PNG)

I think that **this filter should be somehow limited**. Sure, it's fun to use, but it needs to be fixed.

Comment: That's not havoc, that's serious business going on there.

Comment: +1 for capturing my attempt at a super long tag

Comment: I like how you included `[bug]` to report it as a bug at the same time as `[feature-request]` to ask if we can keep it.

Comment: Spoil sport ;).

Comment: I'm soooo tempted to retag this post `pizza`.

Comment: @Andy you mean [status-pizza]?

Comment: @fahadsadah: I think only mods can tag `[status-*]`

Comment: @Andy You could add [status-pizza], it just won't be a red tag. Before Sam got his diamond, he used to use [status-completeded].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about turning it into more of a useful feature?  Make it work with all tags, make them link and on hover pop up some tag stats. Also, make it so that only in use moderator specific tags are red, I think that might "reduce the abuse", so to speak.

Comment: +1 ... but what about an embedded Python interpreter too? ;) I think a good set of tags that have *semantic meaning* is a good thing.

Comment: @Grace Note: It would just link to a page (and pop up on hover) with *0 posts tagged...*. No harm done. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pizza

Comment: Great idea. Should be done client-side!

Comment: @maxim this part is [status-planned] .. the original question.. not so much

Answer (score 11):

**The novelty will wear off**

Everyone just has a new toy; So I wouldn't jump to conclusions here ... give it a while. Everyone is going to go mental until every feature has been abused ... then we will get norm behavior. Maybe tone it down color wise, but have:

`[modmsg-you-will-be-banned]` look more brutal.

Comment: `[status-no-it-wont]`

Answer (score 6):

There are per-site chatroom easter eggs for many sites. This is meta's easter egg.

What are the others? Hmm...